# Can't use execl in C

Tags: c, execl

I am trying to execute this execl command in a C program and it simply doesn't work.

```
execl("~/Desktop/taskc/validating/analyzer/numbers_analyzer", "numbers_analyzer", (char*)NULL);

bash: syntax error near unexpected token `"~/Desktop/taskc/validating/analyzer/numbers_analyzer",
```

I also tried with some validate examples that I've found on Internet and they also don't work. (I'm always getting the same error)

```
execl( "/bin/ls", "/bin/ls", argv[1], NULL );
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `"/bin/ls",'

execl("/bin/date", "date", 0, 0);
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `"/bin/date",'
```

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Can you execute the same command directly in the bash?

Comment: I can't execute those commands either in a program or in the bash... That's why I don't understand what goes wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message you're getting is what happens if you try to input the C function call directly to the shell:

```
[dbush] execl("/bin/date", "date", 0, 0);
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `"/bin/date",'
[dbush]
```

You need to put the code into an actual C program, compile it, and run it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    // the last argument should be a NULL pointer to signal the end of the arg list
    execl("/bin/date", "date", NULL);
}
```

Output:

```
[dbush] gcc  -g -o /tmp/x1 /tmp/x1.c
[dbush] /tmp/x1
Tue Nov 24 20:11:54 UTC 2015
```

Comment: And use [wordexp()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wordexp.3.html) to expand the path name first. It supports the same syntax as POSIX shells, so `~` and `$HOME` (and all other POSIX shell environment variable references) will work.

Comment: Indeed, `wordexp()` should work, whereas the now-deleted suggestion to use `execlp()` to accommodate the tilde-containing path probably would not have worked (the docs require `execlp()` to perform a path search only if the command name does not contain slash characters, and in any case is unlikely to handle `~` as the shell does).

Comment: That works. Thanks! I'll try to fix the first command that I put in the question because that was put in a C program

Comment: @Miguel Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Comment: This is undefined behaviour. you're passing 2 integers, because 1 didn't work; the last argument to `execl` must be `(char *)0`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala  Good catch.  Updated.

Answer (score 0):

On my computer, running ubuntu linux 14.04, using `bash` as the command shell, this command cannot be run from the command line.

However, in the following C program, it works correctly:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE  200112L
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main( void )
{
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if( 0> pid)
    { // then, error
        perror("fork failed");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    if( !pid )
    { // child
        execl( "/bin/ls", "/bin/ls", NULL, NULL );
        perror( "execl failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    printf( "parent running after successful fork\n");
    return 0;
}
```

giving an output that looks like this:

Note: I ran the program from a terminal

In the following output, I trimmed most of the list of files from the 'ls' command.

```
parent running after successful fork
a.out              howToCalcPrimeNumbers(works)    tellwait.c
bashloop.sh        howToCalcPrimeNumbers(works).c  tellwait.h
cards.h            howToCalcPrimeNumbers(works).o  tellwait.h.gch
cards.h.gch        input.txt               tellwait.o
cent_convert.c         libSensors.h            test
```